# How to upload follow-up intent to another parent intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to upload a previously downloaded follow-up intent (in .json) to another parent intent with no success in the Dialogflow page. Error can be seen in image attached
[image]

I've changed "parentId" and "rootParentId" to match the new parent intent without luck...

Answer (score 5):

This is the answer from support team, hope it helps others:

> Currently, Dialogflow doesn't provide a default feature or shortcut in the developer console to put the follow-up intent to a parent intent by uploading JSON files. But you can always achieve this by exporting your agent as a zip file and manually add the "parentId" ("id" of parent intent), "rootParentId" ("id" of root parent intent) fields in the JSON file of the follow-up intent and restore your agent in the developer console with the modified agent zip file.

Comment: This should be marked as accepted.
This is the only way to achieve this, even today.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a way for a user to move a follow-up intent to another parent intent. It's also not possible to transition a top-level intent into a follow-up intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the total dialogflow agent data, and modify the json files in the "intents" folder.

[image: Dialogflow Export Agent]

[image: Exported zip structure]

And there, you will find these values and modify the parentId and rootParentId according to the parent intent's "id". Then recompile the zip, Delete all intents, restore using the modified zip file.

```
{
  "id": "c6f2883a-aa05-46e0-af0e-58dc96ebe7a0",
  "parentId": "21e013a7-091d-40e4-89be-1d6a842d7fd6",
  "rootParentId": "21e013a7-091d-40e4-89be-1d6a842d7fd6",
.....
}
```