# Dialogflow creates followup-2 context

Tags: dialogflow-es

For some reason DialogFlow decides to add an extra followup intent each time I edit existing followup intents and try adding a new one. It's not really game breaking, but really really annoying.

What I expext:

```
Parent Intent (Output Context Parent-followup)
    '-> Child Intent (Input Context Parent-followup)
    '-> Child Intent (Input Context Parent-followup)
```

What I get:

```
Parent Intent (Output Context Parent-followup, Parent-followup-2)
    '-> Child Intent (Input Context Parent-followup)
    '-> Child Intent (Input Context Parent-followup, Parent-followup-2)
```

When I try to remove the Parent-followup-2, The Child Intent is no longer displayed as a followup Intent. As I said, it still works, it just get very chaotic very fast. Is there some way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this Post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51760786/5249411 which talks about DialogFlow not being able to directly set the parent Intent.

The only way of solving this seems to be to download the entire agent as a zip, add the ID of the parent as `parentId` and the ID of the root parent to `rootParentId` and then upload it again.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the output context `Parent-followup-2` in `Parent Intent (Output Context Parent-followup, Parent-followup-2)` and try again to create the followup.