# DialogFlow: follow-up intent automatically moves out to the root level

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm using DialogFlow console. My follow-up intents are supposed to stay inside the parent intents at the sub-level. However, it somehow automatically moves to the root level. (see the pic below)

How could i move it back to the sub-level? DialodFlow doesn't support drag and move within an agent..

[image]

Comment: There's a easier and tricky way to do this ! https://stackoverflow.com/a/71748743/3144572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation of the [follow-up intents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-follow-up-intents), follow-up intent is a child of its associated parent Intent.

Referring to the doc, I created a simple chatbot and it is working as intended and maintains the parent-child hierarchy.

You can refer to the below sample **Appointment** Intent hierarchy.

[image]

**response :**

```
User : book appointment
appointment-followup: today?
User : yes
Appointment-yes-followup : ok we will book it for you this afternoon will that be fine?
User : yes
Appointment-yes-yes-followup : Ok done it will be booked today afternoon


User : book appointment
appointment-followup: today?
User : no
appointment-no-followup : do you want to book tomorrow?
User : yes
Appointment-no-followup : sorry we don't have booking for tomorrow
```

Whenever you create any follow-up intent **it creates an output context that is automatically added to the parent Intent and an input context of the same gets added to the follow-up intent**. **Making changes in the input context of the follow-up intent does not maintain the parent-child hierarchy**.

In my **Appointment-yes-yes follow-up inten**t the input context was **Appointment-yes-followup**, when I tried changing the input context and added my parent intent  in the input context i.e **Appointment**, the follow-up intent went out of the hierarchy.

[image]

[image]

You can also check for the same in the Json response also.

To get the follow-up intent to the sub-level of the parent intent, you need to create the follow-up intent under parent follow-up intent as dialogflow does not provide drag and move option and **the input context of the follow-up intent must contain the parent follow-up intent** .

For example **Appointment-yes-yes** should contain **Appointment-yes followup** in the input context.

Comment: Hey Sandeep thank you for your explanation! i did another test to modify the name of input context of the followup intent, it did change the hierarchy! previous i was just trying to rename it after it had been created ... Finally i knew why this happened (it bothered me a lot as it happened few times)

Comment: Hi Sandeep, i have another question posted here. Appreciate it a lot if you can have a look when you are free! But it's totally fine if not. You already helped me a lot!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69208465/dialogflow-if-an-intent-is-triggered-three-times-how-to-store-and-reuse-the-pa

Comment: Hi @Tao I have posted the answer for your question