# How to insert a Dialogflow ES intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am creating a reservation system in Dialogflow.
I have created a flow to some extent, but I want to insert other intents in the middle of the flow, but I am having trouble understanding where I can do this.

If I can't insert other intents in the middle of the flow, do I have to reconfigure the flow from the beginning?

I tried Dialogflow CX, but the UI was very difficult to understand, so I gave up.

If this is not possible, I would like to ask the following questions as alternatives
Is it possible to pass parameters from an intent in another flow to an independent intent that does not belong to a series of flows? Also, is it possible to pass parameters from an independent intent to an intent in another flow?

Dialogflowで予約システムを作成中です。
ある程度フローを作成したのですが、その途中に他のインテントを挿入したいのですが、どこからできるかがわからず困っております。

途中で他のインテントが挿入できないと、初めからフローを組み直さなければならないのでしょうか？

Dialogflow CXも試してみましたが、UIが非常に理解しづらく、諦めました。

もしできない場合、代替え案として以下を質問したいです。
一連のフローに属さず、独立したインテントに他のフローのインテントのパラメーターを渡すことは可能なのでしょうか？また、独立したインテントから、別のフローのインテントにパラメータを渡すことはできるのでしょうか？？
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNmiu.png)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to inserting new intents into an existing flow, you primarily work with contexts and intent IDs(`id`,`parentId`,`rootParentId`).

1. [**Contexts**](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-overview): Contexts help in controlling the sequence of the conversation. By setting the appropriate input and output contexts in your intents, you can guide the conversation flow.
2. **[follow-up Intents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-follow-up-intents) UI**: Each intent has an `id`, `parentId` and `rootParentId`, as seen in the intent's JSON configuration. By thoughtfully assigning these IDs, you can create a logical structure of follow-up intent.

Related questions:
[How to upload follow-up intent to another parent intent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51760786)

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I've also checked other posts you shared.

I see, so I can add the desired intent not by inserting it through the GUI but by writing JSON and uploading it!

Thank you. I'll give it a try!